# Why does \setkomafont not center chapters, but all other levels of headings?

Tags: koma-script

I am working on redefining `KOMA-Script` to mimic a specific look of a publisher. For this look I need to center all heading levels from `part` to `subsubsection`. The MWE shows only the problem, which is, `\setkomafont` works for all levels but `chapter`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setkomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{16}{0}\selectfont\centering}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{13}{0}\selectfont\centering}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont\centering}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{foo1}
\chapter{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\end{document}
```

But the result is looking like this:
[image]

**Bonus question: Why doesn't the headings of ToC, abbreviations list heading etc. not react on the \centering at all?**

Comment: you are misusing the font commands, centering is not a font.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer, I found answers telling people to do exactly this, but according to Markus Kohm himself (https://komascript.de/node/112) it is misuse and the proper solution is to use: `\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering}` which also works for me and also answers my bonus question.
Do you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it! Or shall I answer it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only font commands should be used in the argument of `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont`. If you want to change the alignment of headings, you can redefine `\raggedpart` (default: `\centering`), `\raggedchapter` (default: `\raggedsection`) and `\raggedsection` (default: `\raggedright`). Note that `\raggedsection` is used for all free-standing headings using `style=section`, eg. `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection`.

If all headings should be centered, redefine `\raggedsection`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% use a scalable font
\setkomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}% <=====
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{foo1}
\chapter{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ToC, LoF etc. are chapters by default. So the alignment of their titles is the same as for chapters.

[image]