# How to center all chapters in koma-script

Tags: formatting, koma-script

Following what I tried

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\centering}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{CHAP1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546198/why-does-setkomafont-not-center-chapters-but-all-other-levels-of-headings

Comment: @Ingmar, thanks a lot!